# Memory space of an operating system

Tags: system-installation, ram, chrome-os

I want to install Uberstudent (based on Ubuntu 14.04) on a Samsung Chromebook 2. I'm new to looking at specs so I don't know if it will work.

The Uberstudent documentation states:

> "*2 GB of memory or more is strongly recommended. 4GB of memory is optimal*"

Is this refering to RAM or Harddrive/SSD-space? What kind of problems will appear if the computer only has 2 GB RAM (if it's refering to RAM)?

Comment: It is referring to RAM and if you don't have enough it will be slow at best and crash at worst.

Answer (score 1):

This following statement is surely referring to RAM only and not the storage-device size.

```
"2 GB of memory or more is strongly recommended. 4GB of memory is optimal"
```

If you have only 2GB RAM then though your OS will function but not as per the expectation. It may slow down few applications OR in worst case, may freeze your OS.

You can watch usage of RAM memory by command
`free -m`
and look at free memory

Also, you can free up your buffered/used memory by command 
`echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches`

Answer (score 1):

"Memory" here refers to **RAM** (Random Access Memory)

RAM is an essential factor for (or bottleneck to) your computer's performance. When the operating system runs out of RAM it will attempt to use the hard disk; this will result in a major blow to your application's performance and potentially (after extended hanging) will end in a crash.

You will experience the performance hit most with a mechanical drive. Even with a considerably faster SSD, delays will still be apparent. To give you some idea, while your SSD might transfer `200 - 1000MB/s` a RAM module might transfer at `5000 - 15,000MB/s`.